# Calculating distance from acceleration equation.

Tags: calculus, dynamical-systems

I need to calculate the distance travelled from an acceleration time equation. I know that integrating the acceleration equation will give me the velocity and integrating that will give the displacement. How should I get distance?

Comment: So you're confused with the words 'dispacement' and 'distance'? If the path is a straight line, those are the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can just take the integral of the absolute value of velocity over time, or the magnitude if more generally it's a vector. Intuitively that's because you add up all the little distances travelled in each time step, regardless of direction to get distance.